# Read YAML file value [.yml is not in /resources folder]

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, yaml

I am new to gradle and trying to read value from poject_setting.yml file that is not in /resources folder. I tried many stackoverflow answers to read the value from poject_setting.yml file but getting null value every time.
Following is the path to the project_setting.yml.

[image]

How I can read the value from poject_setting.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is importing the external config/settings file in the main application properties/yaml file. For example:

```java
// in application.properties
spring.config.import=file:./project_setting.yml
```